# PIE.htc apply on AJAX loaded content ie7,8

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-7, rounded-corners, css3pie

I use pie.htc http://css3pie.com/ for rounded corners in IE7,8 - it works ok on first pageload - but the other content is loaded viw AJAX request.

The new loaded content dons't render pie.htc - the rounded corner isn't applied.

How can this get to work - how can i apply on AJAX loaded content  the

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [PIE.js](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/) for that, can't imagine any other solution.